# FFmpeg conversion of audio to Opus produces larger than expected file

Tags: ffmpeg, opus

I have lots of 16-bit 8KHz wav files that I'm trying to convert into `Opus` format.

Using a sample file, `ffmpeg` converts it in under a second:

`ffmpeg.exe -i file.wav -b:a 24k -c:a libopus FileFromFFmpeg.opus`

> ffmpeg version 5.1.2-essentials_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c)
> 2000-2022 the FFmpeg developers

If I use `opusenc` (from OpusTools), it takes around 3 seconds:

`opusenc --bitrate 24 file.wav FileFromOpusEnc.opus`

> Encoding using libopus 1.4-9-gc8549975 AVX2 [Dec 11 2023] (libopusenc
> 0.2.1-18-gd53a41b AVX2 [Dec 11 2023]) (audio)

Both files play back fine, but the one from FFmpeg is double the size:

- FileFromFFmpeg.opus  - 534958 bytes
- FileFromOpusEnc.opus - 283811 bytes

Looking at the files with `ffprobe`, the only difference is the bitrate:

`FileFromFFmpeg.opus:  Duration: 00:02:24.02, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 29 kb/s`

`FileFromOpusEnc.opus: Duration: 00:02:24.01, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 13 kb/s`

I've tried adding the `-vbr` option to FFmpeg (which is apparently the default), but this doesn't make any difference.

Given how much faster FFmpeg is, I'd like to use it, but I can't get the file size to where it should be. Are there options I'm missing?

Comment: Try adding `-vbr constrained`: `ffmpeg.exe -i file.wav -b:a 24k -c:a libopus -vbr constrained FileFromFFmpeg.opus`. Please note that the desired bitrate is 24kb/s, so don't expect it to be 13 kb/s as opusenc output. There is also `-compression_level` argument as described [here](https://superuser.com/questions/516806/how-to-encode-audio-with-opus-codec).